# UIPopover appearing from wrong button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have an app which takes an image from existing library, or new from camera.

On the iPad, when I press the 'from library' button the popover appears (correctly) above the button from which it was pressed, however when I press the 'take photo' from the camera button, the camera controller appears over the 'from library' button also... I need this to appear over the 'take photo' button otherwise it looks a bit strange!

here is the code used;

```
- (void)pickImageFromLibrary: (id)sender
{
    [Flurry logEvent: @"PickImage"];

    [self openImagePickerWithSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

}


- (void)takePicture: (id)sender
{
    [Flurry logEvent: @"TakeImage"];

    [self openImagePickerWithSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

}

- (void)openImagePickerWithSourceType: (UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if ( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: sourceType] ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString( @"Error", @"" )
                                                        message: NSLocalizedString( @"We are sorry, but this functionality is not available at your device.", @"No camera eror" )
                                                       delegate: nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString( @"Dismiss", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    self.isCameraShown = YES;


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)picker];
        CGRect takePhotoRect;
        takePhotoRect.origin = self.view.frame.origin;
        takePhotoRect.size.width = 1;
        takePhotoRect.size.height = 1;
        [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 216.0)];

        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:_openLibraryButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    }else{
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL ];
    }


}
```

Comment: It looks like you are forcing it to always use the `fromLibrary` frame `[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:_openLibraryButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

Comment: Side note - do not show the camera in a popover. Only use a popover for the photo library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are presenting the popover from the `openLibraryButton`.

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:_openLibraryButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

You need to add checking to see if the `take photo` or `choose from library` button was pressed, then show the popover for that button.

SUDO Code:

```
if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:_openLibraryButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
} else {
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:_takeFromCamera.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi Bot, how would I add the checking part? Do you have an example I could use?

Comment: @DaveBradford you could check the sourceType you are passing in

Comment: Bot - works flawlessly, thank you so much! Marked as accepted!